# SELECT * INTO OUTFILE from a view doesn't work, but the underlying query works fine INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql

I'm running a query that does a calculation based on some views, and writes the results to a file. It looks like this:

```
select `v1`.`id` AS `id`,`v2`.`name` AS `name`,
`v2`.`nbr` AS `nbr`,
`v1`.`nbr` AS `total`,
(`v2`.`nbr` / `v1`.`nbr`) AS `percent`

INTO OUTFILE '/home/username/mysqldump/filename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

from `v2` join `v1`

where `v2`.`id` = `v1`.`id`
```

That works great. I created a view based on this query, but it doesn't work as a drop-in replacement, as I expected. Here's the "Create View" portion of SHOW CREATE VIEW:

```
 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED  DEFINER=`user`@`localhost`
       SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 VIEW `view_name` AS
  select `v1`.`id` AS `id`,
         `v2`.`name` AS `name`,
         `v2`.`nbr` AS `nbr`,
         `v1`.`nbr` AS `total_pvs`,
          (`v2`.`nbr` / `v1`.`nbr`) AS `percent`
  from (`v2` join `v1`) where (`v2`.`id` = `v1`.`id`)
```

Here's the query that doesn't work:

```
 SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/home/username/mysqldump/filename.csv'
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 FROM view_name;
```

I got this error:

`ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'database_name.view_name' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them`

I'm running as root, so I don't think there are any rights issues. What might be making this query invalid in the eyes of MySQL? I'm running version 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

**EDIT**: Running `SELECT * FROM view_name` returns the records as expected. However, with thousands of lines, and the need for solid formatting, I would rather use `INTO OUTFILE`.

Comment: Please show the definition of the view.  You also removed the `FIELDS TERMINATED`, etc., right?

Comment: I did indeed, yes. I added the create view statement so you won't have to just take my word for it. Do you see something odd in there?

Comment: It looks fine.  All I can think of is that the view is not correctly defined by referencing some fields that do not exist.

Comment: Maybe you don't have permission to write to the directory?  Maybe the userid of the writer is not who you think it is?  How are you executing the statement?

Comment: In both cases, I'm executing the statements from `mysql`, the simple command-line tool, logged in as mysql root. I'm going to try it again, just in case. See you in a few hours ... and thanks for looking over the problem.

Comment: Tried again, failed with the same error as in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread is getting a little old, but it has by far the best presentation of the few (unsolved) posts on that subject, so here is what I found:

As you can guess, since the error shows up when you add the "into file" part, the lacking permission is that of accessing files (and yes, the error message is misleading).

Indeed, if you grant the view's definer the global FILE privileges, the error will disappear. (And that makes the error message misleading in a second way, in that it looks like the invoker permissions have no bearing there - though they should, IMHO.)

Answer (score 0):

I would try just running the select without exporting to the file first. 
Select * from outfile

Comment: `SELECT * FROM view_name`, I think you mean. I thought of that, and I'm testing it now. It takes the query a bit to run through. Thanks.

Comment: OK, confirmed. `SELECT * FROM view_name` works. It's dumping thousands of lines into my console right now. Obviously, that is not really what I want, though. I'll edit the question to indicate it's failing on `INTO OUTFILE`